# A problem when i click on edit button, all the other elements listen to the click but i need just the one i click on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>todo</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <h1 class="text">To Do App</h1>
  <hr>
  <div class="input">
  <input id="input-text" type="text" name="" value="">
  <button id="btn">Add</button>
  </div>
  <div class="to-do">
   <h3 class="text color1">TO-do-list</h3>
   <hr>

   <ul id="toDoList">
  
    
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="completed">
   <h3 class="text color">Completed</h3>
  <hr>
   <ul id="completed">
   
    
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "js/todo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  let newTask = $('#input-text');
  if (newTask.val() === '') {
    alert('You need to write something');
  } else {
    let editButton = ('<button class = edit > Edit' + '</button>');
    let finishedButton = ('<button class = finished > Finished' + '</button>');
    let deleteButton = ('<button class = delete > Delete' + '</button>');

    let input = `<input disabled  value="${newTask.val()}" >`;


   
    $('#toDoList').append('<li>' +input+ editButton + finishedButton + deleteButton + '</li>');
  
    
    newTask.val('');
  }
  
  $('.edit').on('click', function() {
   
   $('input').prop('disabled',false);

   

   
  });
  
  $('.finished').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent();
    $('#completed').append($(this).parent());
  });

  $('.delete').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

A problem when i click on edit button, all the other elements listen to the click but i need just the one i click on. It's my first time working with coding, do i have another problems with my code, thank u for help in advance. A problem when i click on edit button, all the other elements listen to the click but i need just the one i click on. It's my first time working with coding, do i have another problems with my code, thx.

Comment: You need to add your html too.

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc Ngoc i added it

Comment: Its Because if you inspect the code, all the inputs have the same class ```class = input ``` and your code is working perfectly and changing all the inputs with the class 'input'. Now, the solution to this should be dynamic classes or ids. Something like ```class = input'+i+' ``` . Here i will keep incrementing every time you click add button thus giving you unique classes for edit buttons and inputs. This should solve the problem. Do tell if any more help needed. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with this code:

```
  $('.edit').on('click', function() {
    $('input').prop('disabled',false);
  });
```

It says ALL elements with class 'edit' will make ALL 'input' elements have disabled removed.

So you will have to make sure the function will only apply to the one you want to edit.

I made [a small edit here](https://codepen.io/Rmaxx/pen/jObEOpR)

just to show you the principal.
I created a counter 'count'.
When adding an item  i up the count by 1 (count++) and asign it to a data- atttribute on the button.

I also give the textfield a unique ID  'field'+count so it will be equal to the editbutton link.

you can see that the onlick will now use the data attribute for each edit button, so it can alter the corresponding field.

There are plenty more ways to do it, but this will show you the thoughts behind the problem..

Comment: just a data attribute, you can read the attribute with jquery .data()

Comment: no problem, if it answers your question please mark the answer... ps: make sure you only use lowercase on the attributes name if you use .data()